# I have looked at various examples of switch statements and none have been able to give me the help I need in fixing the one I need to write

Tags: javascript, image, switch-statement

I need to use a switch statement to switch the picture every 5 seconds during this countdown. For the life of me I cannot figure out what I've done wrong.
My prompt is as follows:
Within the `startAdPage()` function, include two statements: one statement that uses a `setInterval()` method to call a function named `changeAd()` every ﬁve seconds, and another statement that uses a `setInterval()` method to call a function named `startCountdown()` every second. Create the `changeAd()` function so that every ﬁve seconds, it alternates the image in the document body with the three images that are located in your Projects folder for Chapter 4: cvb1.gif, cvb2,gif, and cvb3.gif.  Use a switch statement in the `changeAd()` method to change the images from one to another.
Create the `startCountdown()` function so that it changes the value assigned to the text ﬁeld in the document body to the value of a variable named count, which is decreased by a value of one (from 15 to 1) each time the `startCountdown()` function executes.

Any insight you can provide to help me solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

```
html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CVR.css"/>
    <title>Central Valley Realtors</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*[CDATA[*/

            function startAdPage(){
                     window.setInterval("changeAd()", 5000);
                     window.setInterval("startCountdown()", 1000);
}

            function changeAd(){
                var cvb = document.getElementById("cvbImage").src;
                    switch(cvb){
                        case "images/cvb1.gif":
                        cvb = "images/cvb2.gif";
                        break;
                        case "images/cvb2.gif":
                         cvb = "images/cvb3.gif";
                        break;
                        case "images/cvb3.gif":
                         cvb = "images/cvb1.gif";
                        break;
 }
}

            function startCountdown(){
                var count = document.countdown.timer.value;
                    if(count > 1){
                    document.countdown.timer.value = count - 1;
 }

                    else{
                    window.location = "CVR2.html";
 }     
}
        /*]]*/
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="startAdPage()">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img id="cvbImage" src="images/cvb1.gif" alt=""/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>Advertisement</p>
                <p>
                    The Central Valley Realtors homepage will be displayed in 
                    <form name="countdown"><input type="text" name="timer" value="15"/></form>
                    seconds.
                </p>
                <p><a href="CVR2.html">Skip Advertisement</a></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: `ChangeAd()` sets the variable `cvb`, but never puts the new value into the `src` attribute of the image.

Comment: Why are you passing the callback functions as strings?

Comment: @Barmar How would I go about putting in the new `src` attribute? I suppose I'm not understand the syntax appropriate for the switch statement.

Comment: @steveas This is the only way I was taught to callback these functions. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @JackieB See Mike W's answer.

Comment: @JackieB You misspelled steveax's name. Use SO's name completion feature.

Comment: He's suggesting that you write `setInterval(changeAd, 5000)` -- just pass the function, not a string to execute.

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
var cvb = document.getElementById("cvbImage").src;
```

You're reading the current value of the image src, but you never update it after deciding which image to display next.

Somewhere you need to do this:

```
document.getElementById("cvbImage").src = cvb;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. By adjusting some of the code I've been able to get it to switch from the first image to the second but for some reason it will not switch to the third code. Do you know why this would happen?

Comment: If you've changd the code from what you have posted here already I can't help - I don't know what your code does now.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the form of the switch statement. This is what I've been stuck with now.

```
 function startAdPage() {
window.setInterval("startCountdown()", 1000);
window.setInterval("changeAd()", 5000);
```

}

```
 function startCountdown() {
var count = document.countdown.timer.value;
if (count > 1) {
    document.countdown.timer.value = count - 1;
    return count;
} else {
    window.location = "CVR2.html";
}
```

}

```
function changeAd(count) {
/*if(count = "10"){
 window.alert("Yes");
 }
 else{
 window.alert("No");
 }*/

switch(count) {
    case "10":
        document.getElementById("cvbImage").src = "images/cvb2.gif";
        return count;
        break;
    case "5":
        document.getElementById("cvbImage").src = "images/cvb3.gif";
        break;
}
```

}